# How can I redirect sub-domain to primary domain?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, dns, web-config

I have a scenario where I have two domains pointing to same server one is the primary domain to all sub-sites and then there is secondary domain for each sub-site so what I am trying to do is redirecting the secondary domain to primary domain using web.config file.

For Example: if some one enters `www.domain-secondary.com` it should redirect to `www.domain.com/subsite`

**update:** As per some answers on this question and with some amendments i managed to made it work but apparently it only works if domain doesn't contains any special characters such as æ,ø,å. how can i resolve this issue? Please help

Non-working code which contains special characters

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.skivebøligmøntering\.dk$" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.skive.dk/skive-boligmontering/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: @TZHX it was by mistake Please ignore it

Answer (score 1):

Try this one .

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}"
                  redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it didn't help still its not redirecting to primary domain

Comment: I had to change some parameters in order to make this code work but still there is a problem with a domain where it contains special characters ?? any suggestions